# Issues with variable scopes in PHP

Tags: php

I have just written a program to check for the variable scopes in PHP. The code goes like this:

```
<?php
$value = 1;
function change_value(){
    if(some_condition){
        $value = 0;
        $asset = 1;
    }else{
        $asset = 0;
    }
    return $asset;
}
echo $value;
change_value();
echo $value;
?>
```

Now, the output of the above program is `11`.
How can I change the value of `$value` once it enters the function `change_value()` ?

Comment: It echo's twice 1 ... You see it as 11, yes because you dont have a break entered in your code.

Comment: Read about [references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: or you use it as a parameter and return the value, or you're using a global variable.

Comment: So... what's the difference ? The ways we have outlined still solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parameter `by reference`:

```
<?php
$value = 1;
function change_value(&$value){
    if(/* some_condition */){
        $value = 0;
        $asset = 1;
    }else{
        $asset = 0;
    }
    return $asset;
}
echo $value; // echoes 1
$asset = change_value($value);
echo $value; // echoes 0
echo $asset; // echoes 0 or 1 depending on /* some_condition */
?>
```

Please don't use `global ...` even if some suggest it.
It's bad. It let's the variable be accessable from all over the script and you will be very confused when you come upon the situation where you access `$value` in a different script you included and it acts different then...

Comment: Thank you so much!
I'll be accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Hey, this solution worked for me but I couldn't actually understand the functionality. 
Why was my code not able to change that but passing by reference did so?
I read [PHP Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) but still I am confused a bit. Can you please help?

Comment: @Tushki You have to put something into a function that you can process and return new data, or pass by reference to directly change the variable. When you put a variable into a function without `&`, PHP will create a copy of the variable internally and work with it. When you put in by reference `&$variable`, it does not create a copy. When you put nothing into the function, well, nothing can be changed based on nothing. When a variable is not in scope (when you are in a function or class for example), PHP doesn't *see* the variable from within the function.

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do, goes against common principles, but.

```
$GLOBALS['value'] = 0;
```

Using this inside function will let you change that value, but I suggest you not to do this.

The way others have outlined, is far more right.

Comment: You post an answer but suggest not doing that? Where's the logic? xD

Comment: OP asked to change value ONCE it is inside the function. Without modifying the code (thus using parameter/return || reference) the method I used solves the problem. The other method is just fine, but it breaks what OP was asking.

Comment: You can provide a simple working solution, or you can provide a working solution + best practice / educational effects.

Comment: I was going to post it but since I didn't write it in the first time, and I saw You posted it just after me, I edited and outlined your way was more advised, that's all.

Comment: @Kei +1, appreciated!